# How to do Getmapping("/login") with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql

I try to do a login autentification in spring boot but always present a problem when try to running the validation could you please help me i need this

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public int loginuservalidation(@Pathvarible ("user") String user, @Pathvairable ("password") String password){
return profileInterface.loginuservalidate(user,password);
}
```

What is the reason that i did this is because i need to call this from angular
i have te validation but in java i need to validate the connectivity i am using mysql db

I have this as connectivity only i want to validate if the user is available in my db with an system say "Succes" else "Denied" i dont need session because i did the session in angular

```
  int status = 0;
        try {
            Connection con = getConection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into profileuser(name,user,email,number,password) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, prof.getName());
            ps.setString(2, prof.getUser());
            ps.setString(3, prof.getEmail());
            ps.setString(4, prof.getNumber());
            ps.setString(5, prof.getPassword());
            status = ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
```

Only i want to validate if the user and password exist system say "Succes" else "Denied"

Could you please help me with this?

Example This is my controller

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    ProfileInterface profileInterface;
    //private final static Logger LOGGER= Logger.getLogger(ProfileController.LOGGER.getClass());


    @PostMapping("/saveProfile")
    public int saveProfile(@RequestBody ProfileDto prof){
        return profileInterface.saveprofile(prof);
    }


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public int loginuservalidation(@Pathvarble ("user") String user, 
    @Pathvairable ("password") String password){
        return profileInterface.loginuservalidate(user,password);
    }
}
```

This is my interface and my implementation

```
public interface ProfileInterface {
    int saveprofile(ProfileDto prof);

    int loginuservalidate(String user, String password);
}

@Component
public class ProfileImplem implements ProfileInterface {

    public static Connection getConection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/profiledb", "root", "root");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }

    @Override
    public int saveprofile(ProfileDto prof) {
        int status = 0;
        try {
            Connection con = getConection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into profileuser(name,user,email,number,password) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, prof.getName());
            ps.setString(2, prof.getUser());
            ps.setString(3, prof.getEmail());
            ps.setString(4, prof.getNumber());
            ps.setString(5, prof.getPassword());
            status = ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }


The problem is when i send this Method
    > @Override
    >         public int loginuservalidate(String user, String password) {
    >              Connection con = getConection();
    >             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from profileuser where user=? and password=?");
    >             ps.setString(1, prof.getUser());
    >             ps.setString(2, prof.getPassword());
    >             status = ps.executeUpdate();
    > 
    >           if(user.equals(user)&& password.equals(password)){
    >         System.out.println("Success")          
    >         }else{
    >         System.out.println("Sorry te user no exist in DB")   
    >          }
    >         }
    >     }


in angular i send this the front end is working but backend doesnt working :(

      <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user">User:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" aria-labelledby="userhelp" placeholder="" name="user" required [(ngModel)]="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="" [(ngModel)]="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="checkLogin()">Submit</button>
              </form>
```

Comment: Yey, confidential information in URL parameters combined with plaintext passwords in database - I'm not going near this with a barge pole. Use Spring Security, let it do this for you safely and correctly.

Comment: Spring security is because we want to save the session with angular also i try to looking a tutorial about to spring security but i dont find anything

Comment: No, it's not. Spring Security is when you want to provide security - it has many modes of operation including sessionless. I don't understand your comment about tutorials, there are not only a plethora of tutorials but also excellent documentation.

Comment: @BoristheSpider is right, but that's another story. It's unclear to me how this two code snippets relate to each other. Would be helpful, if you post the `loginuservalidate` method for instance and formulate a good question. Don't know what a good question is? Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello peter let me do an example

Comment: Use  @ Pathvariable instead @ Pathvarble

Comment: i did that. x.x